# Selenium driver.find_elements_by_xpath; why is there no data returned

Tags: python, selenium

Specs for the below question, I am using:

```
selenium (version 3.141.0)
Chrome (version 76)
wsl
python (version 3.5.3)
```

The aim of the below script is to, for each of the drop downs on this page, extract the Reference, Plant, Direction and Disease columns, i.e. i want to pull down the info in all the grey boxes data like this:

[image]

This code brings me to the page I want:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.binary_location=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='/mnt/c/Users/kela/Desktop/selenium/chromedriver.exe')

#get the url
driver.get('http://147.8.185.62/services/NutriChem-2.0/')


#find the food name
element = driver.find_element_by_id("input_food_name")
element.send_keys("22663")


#click food-disease association
element = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name=food_search_section]'))
element.select_by_value('food_disease')


#click submit and click plant-disease associations
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="Submit"]').click()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('frame'))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[onclick*="plant-disease"]').click()


#to click into each drop down table rows
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='Level1Table']/tbody/tr[contains(@name,'hList')]/td/img[contains(@id,'imgList')]")
print(rows) #this is empty
```

Because once I can loop through the tables that I want, i think i just need to do something like this to extract the data:

```
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        food_source = row.find_all('td')[1].text
        pmid = row.find_all('td')[0].text
        disease = row.find_all('td')[3].text
        #haven't figured out how to get the association direction yet
        print(food_source + '\t' + pmid + '\t' + disease + '\t' + association_direction)
```

I have two specific questions:

1. Can someone point out why print(rows) is empty/where I'm going wrong in finding the data in the grey tables to extract?
2. Is the idea/method that i have to extract the data the best method?

Comment: If `rows` is empty, it's because `.find_elements_by_xpath()` didn't find any elements with that xpath.  i.e. your xpath is wrong.  We can't tell the xpath from the images you posted, so we don't know _why_ it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath is correct. It is failing because it is on different frames. I am able to output total rows in the table.

```
time.sleep(3)
#to click into each drop down table rows
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('mainFrame'))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('ListWeb'))

rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='Level1Table']//tr[contains(@name,'hList')]")
print(len(rows))
```

The output is

> 62

To answer your 2nd question - the data is available in DOM. I think  you don't need to click through each row to scrape it. you can directly scrape it from this table.