# Selenium driver: find elements by xpath; how do i parse a level 2 table (i.e. a table within a table)

Tags: python, selenium

I asked a question to get me to this point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498933/selenium-driver-find-elements-by-xpath-why-is-there-no-data-returned/57499464#57499464), except since this was a specific different question I have it separate, but let me know if this isn't the right place.

I have this script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.binary_location=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='/mnt/c/Users/kela/Desktop/selenium/chromedriver.exe')

#get the url
driver.get('http://147.8.185.62/services/NutriChem-2.0/')


#find the food name
element = driver.find_element_by_id("input_food_name")
element.send_keys("22663")


#click food-disease association
element = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name=food_search_section]'))
element.select_by_value('food_disease')


#click submit and click plant-disease associations
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="Submit"]').click()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('frame'))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[onclick*="plant-disease"]').click()


#to click into each drop down table rows
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('mainFrame'))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('ListWeb'))
```

This gets me to the page I want to scrape [image]:

The next stage, for each of the grey boxes, I want to pull out (1) the PMID ID, (2) Plant, (3) direction (signified by whether the image is up_arrow.png or down_arrow.png, so just printing the image name is fine) and (4) The disease.

As you can see from my previous question, I am very new to selenium, and thought once I got to this stage, I would just loop through the table rows and print these with beautifulSoup. The short version of my issue is I just cannot get this to work.

Things I have tried:

Attempt 1:

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='Level1Table']//tr[contains(@name,'hList')]")
test_row = rows[0]
print(test_row.text)
```

This above code will print 'Pomegranate Osteoartritis 3'; but then I can't work out how to loop within this (I just get empty data).

Attempt 2:
Then I tried to loop through each r in rows, but that still only gives me the level 1 data. (i.e. just prints multiple lines of attempt 1).

Attempt 3:

```
rows = Select(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='Level2Table']//tr[contains(@name,'hList')]"))
print(rows)
```

Above, I wondering why can't I just run the same as attempt 1, but looping through the level 2 tables instead of level 1. This output is empty. I'm not sure why this doesn't work; I can see from inspecting the page that the level2table is there.

Attempt 4:
This was the way I was originally thinking of doing it, but it doesn't work:

```
for row in rows.findAll('tr'):
        food_source = row.find_all('td')[1].text
        pmid = row.find_all('td')[0].text
        disease = row.find_all('td')[3].text
        #haven't figured out how to get the association direction yet
        print(food_source + '\t' + pmid + '\t' + disease + '\t' + association)
```

This is my first selenium script, so at this point I'm just out of my depth. Could someone please show me how to loop through the level 2 tables within the level 1 table and extract the required info (reference, plant, direction and disease).

Edit 1: Based on Guy's suggestion below, this is the full script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.binary_location=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='/mnt/c/Users/kela/Desktop/selenium/chromedriver.exe')

#get the url
driver.get('http://147.8.185.62/services/NutriChem-2.0/')


#find the food name
element = driver.find_element_by_id("input_food_name")
element.send_keys("22663")


#click food-disease association
element = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name=food_search_section]'))
element.select_by_value('food_disease')


#click submit and click plant-disease associations
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="Submit"]').click()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('frame'))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[onclick*="plant-disease"]').click()


#to click into each drop down table rows
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('mainFrame'))
#driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('ListWeb'))

#rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='Level1Table']//tr[contains(@name,'hList')]")
#test_row = rows[0]

driver.switch_to.frame('ListWeb') # no need for find_element, name or id are sufficient
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id^="ListTAXID"] [name^="Item"]')
for row in rows:
        row_data = row.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td')
        pmid = row_data[0].text
        plant = row_data[1].text
        direction = row_data[2].get_attribute('src')
        disease = row_data[3].text
        print(str(pmid) + '\t' + str(plant) + '\t' + str(direction) + '\t' + str(disease))
```

That leads to this output:

```
        None
        None
        None
        None
        None
        None
        None
        None
        None
        None
        None
        None
```

Comment: Please, share the HTML of the tables you wish to extract data from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner table is not part of the header row (with `'Pomegranate Osteoartritis 3'` text), but inside a sibling row that is not visible.

Those rows has `id` attribute that start with `ListTAXID` that can help identify them, and the data you are looking for is in a descendant elements with `name` attribute that start `Item`.

The text will be available only if the table is open. You can click on all the header rows before collecting the data, or use `get_attribute('innerText')` instead of `text`, it will get the data even if the table is still closed.

```
driver.switch_to.frame('ListWeb') # no need for find_element, name or id are sufficient

rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id^="ListTAXID"] [name^="Item"]')
for row in rows:
    row_data = row.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td')
    pmid = row_data[0].get_attribute('innerText')
    plant = row_data[1].get_attribute('innerText')
    direction = 'up_arrow' if 'up_arrow' in row_data[2].find_element_by_xpath('.//img').get_attribute('src') else 'down_arrow'
    disease = row_data[3].get_attribute('innerText')
```

As a side note, you should maximize your window `driver.maximize_window()`

Comment: thanks, can i just check is this tested or untested, just because I'm getting: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find_all'?

Comment: @Slowat_Kela I took it from your code. You can use `row.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td')` instead, see updated answer.

Comment: thanks I've just edited my above question to add in your code and what the output looks like, if you can see my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Once you are on the page you want to scrape.

```
import pandas as pd

raw = driver.page_source
soup = bs(raw,'lxml')

df = pd.read_html(soup.prettify(),attrs={'class':'Level2Table'})
```

I think `pandas` will be the right way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

With [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup)

```
# to click into each drop down table rows
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('mainFrame'))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('ListWeb'))

page = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
items = page.select(".Level2Table tr[name^='Item']")
for item in items:
    item_data = item.select("td")
    pmid = item_data[0].text
    plant = item_data[1].text
    direction = "up" if "up_arrow.png" in item_data[2].select_one("img").attrs["src"] else "down"
    disease = item_data[3].text
    print(f"pmid: {pmid}, plant: {plant}, direction: {direction}, disease: {disease}")
```